# Unknown server tag "ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender"

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using ajaxcontrols and in that all controls are working well But I had not found any of the control named as HtmlEditorExtender so I had just copied this tag in .html page

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"%>


<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="Server" />
<ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender TargetControlID="txtComments" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtComments" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

here  is working fine but the problem arises on  , then i downloaded [Nuget.tool](http://www.nuget.org) on reading some of the problems facing just like me but still its not working

what shall I do?

My Web.config file is

```
  <configuration>

<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>

<pages>
  <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
  </controls>
  <sanitizer defaultProvider="AntiXssSanitizerProvider">
    <providers>
      <add name="AntiXssSanitizerProvider" type="AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider" />
    </providers>
  </sanitizer>
</pages>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add `<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="Server" />`

```
    <%@ Register
Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"
Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor"
TagPrefix="HTMLEditor" %>
```

add folowing tag in your web.config

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
<pages>
  <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
  </controls>
</pages>
```

and in page

```
<ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender ID="replyBody_HtmlEditorExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True" OnImageUploadComplete="saveFile"  ClientIDMode="AutoID" EnableSanitization="true"  TargetControlID="replyBody">
```

Comment: which version you are using?

Comment: in config section add section groups system.web tag add inside configuration tab

Comment: removed config sections and try

Comment: on running just simple page i am getting error on <sanitizer defaultProvider="AntiXssSanitizerProvider">

Comment: well remove all the section which i said to add just add page lvl attributes and check

Comment: on down u have written <ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender ../>   and top TagPrefix="HTMLEditor" %>...is it ok???

Comment: ok...i have removed new version of ajaxtoolkit which does not have htmleditorcontrol and in that its showing error as "unknown server tag 'ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender'"

Comment: i will make a project and share it to you

Comment: no i am working on new 1 which u said to download and saying the problem

Comment: https://app.box.com/s/07yq0vc6rzqiy7e96m3j download from here. it has latest version with SanitizerProviders

Comment: I have downloaded from there and this is working...In this if i want to implement calibri font ..is it possible??? or it has also control as <ajaxToolkit:RemoveFormat /> <ajaxToolkit:BackgroundColorSelector />.......or it has just a limitation????

Comment: yes you can do that ... just go through below url in which you will understand what are the things you can do http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/HTMLEditorExtender/HTMLEditorExtender.aspx

Comment: you have to download the source code from http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#ReadMe.html and add desired fonts definitions to _createButton function in  HtmlEditorExtenderBehavior.Pre.js file, rebuild solution and use customized toolkit dlls.you can view http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Client/MicrosoftAjax.Extended/HtmlEditorExtender/HtmlEditorExtenderBehavior.Pre.js

Answer (score 0):

Try using ScriptManager instead of ToolkitScriptManager.

In my project, i'm also working with Editor control (ajax toolkit control) instead of HtmlEditorExtender. A Editor control do the same as the HtmlEditorExtender and you can have three panels Design Mode, HTML Mode and Preview Mode.

If you want to use Editor control instead just add the following register:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor"    TagPrefix="asp" %>
```

Hope it helps.