# HtmlEditorExtender is not a know element after adding all references and prefixes

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using HtmlEditorExtendor in my project but it says :

**HtmlEditorExtender is not a know element .**

I've Tried : [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20297043/unknown-server-tag-ajaxtoolkithtmleditorextender)

But nothing seems to work for me .

I've added all references but still it's not working .

Here is my code :

Assemble after page directive before the asp:Content :

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
```

Here is the code for script manager and htmlEditorExtendor :

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_description" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="250" />
<asp:HtmlEditorExtender ID="HtmlEditorExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txt_description" EnableSanitization="false">
</asp:HtmlEditorExtender>
```

The same page has asp:UpdatePanel which is working fine but asp:HtmlEditorExtender is not working .

Kindly help.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It has been removed since version 15.1. You can just use the normal ScriptManager.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

[Source](https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ToolkitScriptManager%20Removed%20in%20v15.1%2C%20Use%20ScriptManager)